# Problem in obtaining expected value

Tags: integration, statistics, probability-distributions, expected-value

Suppose that we have the following probability density function
\begin{equation}
f(x)=\frac{\alpha x_m^{\alpha}}{x^{\alpha+1}}, \quad x>x_m
\end{equation}
and its cumulative density function
\begin{equation}
F(x)=1-\left(\frac{x_m}{x}\right)^{\alpha}, \quad x>x_m
\end{equation}
I calculate expected value of $X$ in two ways.
First way:
\begin{eqnarray}
\int_{x_m}^{\infty}xf(x)dx&=&\int_{x_m}^{\infty}\frac{\alpha x_m^{\alpha}}{x^{\alpha}}dx\\
&=&\frac{\alpha x_m}{\alpha-1},\quad \alpha>1
\end{eqnarray}
Second way:
\begin{eqnarray}
\int_{x_m}^{\infty}(1-F(x))dx&=&\int_{x_m}^{\infty} \left(\frac{x_m}{x}\right)^{\alpha} dx\\
&=&\frac{x_m}{\alpha-1},\quad \alpha>1
\end{eqnarray}
why the second way gives an incorrect answer? I do not know where I am doing wrong.

Comment: How is this [distribution-theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/distribution-theory)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the second method you have to add $\int_0^{x_m} (1-0)dx=x_m$ (since $f(x)=0$ for $0<x<x_m$). Now you get the same answer as in the first method.

[The general formula for the mean of  a positive random variable is $\int_0^{\infty} (1-F(x))dx$].